# Lazy Initialization in custom IDependencyResolver with Windsor Castle

Tags: c#, arguments, castle-windsor, interceptor

I am using Windsor Castle. I have a Business class and an Interceptor configured as following:

```
windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IMyBusinessInterface>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyBusinessClass>()
    .Interceptors<MyInterceptorAttribute>()
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

`IMyBusinessInterface` and `MyBusinessClass` are inside the project `Business`.
`MyInterceptorAttribute` is inside the project `Interceptors`.
`Business` project has a reference to `Interceptors` project.

`MyInterceptorAttribute` is used as data annotation on a method of the `MyBusinessClass`

```
[MyInterceptorAttribute]
public class MyBusinessClass 
{
    public IUnitOfWork uow { get; set; }
    public MyBusinessClass(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        uow = uow;
    }

    [MyInterceptorAttribute]
    public MyReturnValue MyBusinessMethod(MyArguments arguments)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I need to pass (or retrieve) inside the `MyInterceptorAttribute` class **the same instance** of the `unit of work` that has been instanciated inside the container of Windsor Castle.

In this moment I pass two different instances.

I cannot retrieve the instance of unit of work inside the `MyInterceptorAttribute` because to get the invocation.InvocationTarget I would create a circular reference.

```
public class MyInterceptorAttribute : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        IMyBusinessInterface obj = invocation.InvocationTarget as MyBusinessClass; //I cannot do this because of circular reference

        //obj.uow = ..

    }
}
```

So I was thinking to add a public property of unit of work inside the `MyInterceptorAttribute` and get same instance of unit of work of the business class via dependency injection... something like this:

```
public class MyInterceptorAttribute : IInterceptor
{
    public IUnitOfWork uow { get; set; }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //uow...            
    }
}
```

But in this moment I get two different instances. Is it possible to get the same instance modifying for example the configuration of windsor caste... I suppose using `DependsOn` or `DynamicParameters` or something similar?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing your interceptor as an attribute, which is instantiated by the .Net runtime and therefore not available for dependency injection by Windsor, try using the standard `[Interceptor(typeof(MyInterceptor))]` attribute.

You can then register `MyInterceptor`in Windsor with whatever lifestyle you wish and dependency injection for the Unit Of Work, or any other dependency, will work as expected.